# custom widget in custom page footer

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, footer

looking for some help. I have created a custom page with url:

```
http://localhost/magento2/hello_mvvm/hello/world
```

and here is a code from,

> view/frontend/layout/hello_mvvm_hello_world.xml

code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block
                template="content.phtml"
                class="Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Block\Main"
                name="pulsestorm_helloworld_mvvm"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

some how I need to add my custom created widget to my custom created above mentioned page in the footer container place, can some one assist me?

**My custom widget placed in**

> app/code/Toptal/CustomWidget

This is how my frontend/layout code looks like now where I'm trying to include custom widget: (i think missing name="" value, but I dont know correct what should be)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block
                template="content.phtml"
                class="Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Block\Main"
                name="pulsestorm_helloworld_mvvm"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"> 
        <block template="samplewidget.phtml" 
               class="Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget" 
               name=""/> 
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Comment: What class and template use your widget?

Comment: template name: samplewidget.phtml , class if I'm right is: Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget ?

Comment: My code looks now: 
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block
                template="samplewidget.phtml"
                class="Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget"
                name=""/>
    </referenceContainer>

Answer (score 1):

First you have add your block name then you need to move your block like below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container"> 
    <block template="samplewidget.phtml" 
           class="Toptal\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\Samplewidget" 
           name="widget.name"/> 
</referenceContainer>

<move element="widget.name" destination="footer-container" before="-"/>
```